# Add labels on bar chart Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael, label

I want to put for each bar from barchart a label to generate a dinamic link for each bar. attr(href: "http://site.com/label". When i call label() method debuger tell me that an intern method not exist.

This is my call for labeling bar chart:

```
paper.barchart(x, y, sizeX, sizeY, date, attr).hover(fin, fout).attr({opacity: .5}).label(["positive", "negative", "neutre", ""], date);
```

This is error from firebug

```
    l.labelise is not a function
label(y=["positive", "negative", "neutre", ""], Z=[41, 33, 26, 100])g.bar-min.js (line 7)
chartBar(paper=a { customAttributes={...}, ca={...}, width=900, more...}, x=550, y=680, sizeX=100, sizeY=150, date=[41, 33, 26, 100])slider.js (line 267)
textSlider()slider.js (line 337)
f(b=Document details.html, f=[function()])jquery-1.7.min.js (line 2)
f(b=Document details.html, c=[function()])jquery-1.7.min.js (line 2)
f(a=undefined)jquery-1.7.min.js (line 2)
f()jquery-1.7.min.js (line 2)
[Break On This Error] (function(){var f=Math.min,a=Math.max;...){return new d(this,h,l,j,g,i,k)}})();
g.bar-min.js (line 7)
```

This seems to be an error in library. Know anyone a method to generate a dinamic link for each bar ?

later edit: http://jsfiddle.net/devth/rKjEj/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution i found is the following:

```
paper.barchart(/*parameters*/).each(function (){
          this.attr({ href: "your/address" }); 
})
```

L.E.: http://jsfiddle.net/urmelinho/rKjEj/22/